# jquery validation: required dependency, multiple select options

Tags: jquery

I use the following to make a certain field (field1) a required field, dependant on the select option, (opt1) being selected:

```
    field1: {
    required: function() {
    return $("#selectfield").val() == "opt1";
}
}
```

This works fine but I can't figure out how to add extra options that I would like to make dependant required of the same field.
E.g. op1, opt2, op3

Comment: So you are saying that you want `#venue` to have either opt1, opt2 or opt3 selected?

Comment: Your title makes no sense. Also, are you using some sort of validation plugin? If so, you should tag your question appropriately.

Comment: You can try like this $('select.foo option:selected').val();

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are trying to select multiple options in a select list, the following will select options with the values `op1` and `opt2`:

```
$("#field1 option[value='opt1']").attr('selected', true);
$("#field1 option[value='opt2']").attr('selected', true);
```